# Dynamic chaining with already enqueued work using WorkManager

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am trying to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for my usecase. I have a chat application which is supposed to send messages in order so for that I can use unique work name with `ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.APPEND`:

```
workManager.enqueueUniqueWork("SEND_MESSAGE", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.APPEND , sendMessage);
```

However there is another requirement; a message can contain several images that should be uploaded first before sending the message with uploaded image ids. I can easily utilize `WorkContinuation` mechanism so that when user hits send, app first uploads images and then sends that message but for perceived performance, I want to start uploading the image as soon as it has been picked wether or not the message has been sent yet. So if user hits "send message" button while image is being uploaded, I want to be able to create a chain from existing work. 
Is such dynamic chaining provided by `WorkManager`? Any clever ways to handle this situation with `WorkManager`?

One approach that I can think of is when user hits send, start the send message worker and then inside `doWork`, block the execution and wait for image upload workers to finish `getWorkInfosByTag("UPLOAD_WORK")`. Is this approach good?

Comment: What happens to the images you're uploading if the user decide to not send the message?
If the user discard the message do you want to be able to stop the image uploads?

Comment: yes. User can remove images from composer, uploaded or not, and for that I can just call `workManager.cancelAllWorkByTag("UNIQUE_TAG_FOR_THIS_IMAGE")`.

Comment: I think that then a possible problem (adding these uploads to a chain) is that the whole chain is cancelled.
This is the current behavior, however the team is evaluating updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/134613984